# Is it possible to assign a generic function to a variable?

Tags: swift

```
func function1(arg: Int) -> Int { return arg }

func function2<T>(arg: T) -> T { return arg }

let f1 = function1 // No problem

let f2 = function2<Int> // Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function
```

A current short coming of the language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can let Swift infer the specialization of `function2` by the explicit type annotation of `f2`:

```
let f2: (Int) -> Int = function2
```

Alternatively, use an intermediate specializer function which supplies the explicit type annotation

```
func specialize1Dmap<T>(_ f: @escaping (T) -> T, as _: T.Type) -> (T) -> T { return f }
let f2int = specialize1Dmap(function2, as: Int.self)
let f2str = specialize1Dmap(function2, as: String.self)
```

Comment: Great! And, the same thing works if I pass function2 an argument where a parameter of type (Int) -> Int is required. Thank you, @dfri.