# Assigning a Function with Generic Parameter to a Variable

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to assign a function, which takes a generic parameter, to a variable.

I have a class, Loudspeaker, with a function, saySomething. The saySomething function is meant to take as a parameter any object conforming to the protocol SpeakProtocol:

```
class Loudspeaker {
    func saySomething<T:SpeakProtocol> (speaker:T) {
        print("\(speaker.thinkOfSomethingToSay())")
    }
}

protocol SpeakProtocol {
    func thinkOfSomethingToSay() -> String
}
```

The ThingSayer class implements SpeakProtocol:

```
class ThingSayer:SpeakProtocol {
    func thinkOfSomethingToSay() -> String {
        return "Hello"
    }
}
```

I create a new member of the Loudspeaker class:

```
var aLoudspeaker:Loudspeaker
```

And I would like to assign the saySomething function (not the result of that function) to a variable:

```
var speakFunction = aLoudspeaker.saySomething
```

I would then invoke this function elsewhere by creating a ThingSayer and passing that to speakFunction:

```
var aSpeaker:Thingsayer
speakFunction(speaker:thingSayer)
```

The problem is with this line:

```
var speakFunction = aLoudspeaker.saySomething
```

Which gives me an error: "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred."

I've been beating my head against a wall for quite a while with this. Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

This is obviously a contrived example, but the gist of the problem is that I have a function, which takes a generic parameter, and I want to assign that function to a variable to be invoked elsewhere in my code. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to assign a generic function to a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694060/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-generic-function-to-a-variable)

Comment: Yes, this appears to be the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var speakFuction: (speaker: ThingSayer) -> Void = aLoudspeaker.saySomething
```

You'll need to explicit the type of your function when declaring the variable to help the compiler.

Comment: This does seem to work, but what if I want to invoke the function later with a speaker of a different type (that also conforms to SpeakProtocol)? Is such a thing possible?This is why I was trying to use a generic parameter in the first place. But if I'm locked into one class, then there doesn't seem to be much value in using generics in this case.

Comment: Then why not define `saySomething` as `func saySomething(speaker: SpeakProtocol)`? (without the generic)

Comment: Can you set a protocol as the parameter type in that way?

Comment: Yes. This is the most common way of using them actually. Note that some protocols (ones that have Self or associated type requirements) can't be used as such. But in the above case, this is completely doable.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do, thank you. Somehow I missed this in the documentation and thought I had to use a generic T and check for conformance with my protocol. You've been incredibly helpful.

Comment: Also, I accepted your answer because it solved the immediate question, but it was really the below comment that accomplished my actual goal.